# Query Posts / Products in No Products Found Page with Pagination doesn't work due to Parameters in URL

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, pagination

I'm trying to display the best Selling Product on the no-products-found.php template with pagination (Infinite Loading). Everything works fine BUT the Pagination call for the next page returns a 404 due to the search Parameters in the URL like `/online-shop/?s=nothing&product_cat=0&post_type=product`

The page tries to load the second page with the current URL (see `.../page/2/...`) which returns the already mentioned 404 not found Error.

```
...online-shop/page/2/?s=nothing&product_cat=0&post_type=product
```

**Is there any way to change the Query Function to call the next set of Products URL without Parameters like `..../online-shop/page/2/` ?**

I query and output the products with the following lines of code (no-products-page.php)

```
<?php 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $args = array(
        'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'post_type' => 'product',           
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $paged
    );                  

    query_posts($args);

get_template_part('index', 'no-products-found-bestsellers');
?>
```

and (index-no-products-found-bestseller.php)

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

...

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

...

<?php endwhile; ?>

...

<?php endif; ?>
```